# Hypothesis Testing: t or z distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

If we want to to do hypothesis testing when the sample size is small but the population standard deviation is known, do we use z or t distribution?

Comment: Z-test, it is more correct.

Comment: Even if the sample size is small?

Comment: The difference between the z-test and t-test is not in the sample size. You use the z-test when the population variance is known as it will give more accurate results. T-test you would use when the population variance is not known. You would not decide between the two based on sample size. If anything, you would use a z-test in this case since the t-test is only an approximation to the z-test (asimptotically).

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a specific application in mind? With data where a t-test (or z-test) could be appropriate, continuous data, it is rather rare that you really *know* the standard deviation (outside of textbook exercises.)  So the z-test is mainly a (questionable) didactic tool. This question have nothing to do with sample size!

So, in practical use (outside of textbook exercises), you should simply use the t-test, period. Unless you have a very specific (and unusual) situation, in which case you should tell us.  How can you *really* know the standard deviation?